# Is there a clipboard on non-GUI Ubuntu / Linux systems? Can I synchronize it with my local (OS X) clipboard?

Tags: linux, ssh, xterm, clipboard, xforwarding

I spend a lot of time on Mac OS X as a desktop system, and on the Mac there are two nice little utilities for the command line, `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` which can accept `stdin` and write to `stdout`. **Is there a similar utility or non-GUI pasteboard in linux? How does that work?**

I read over this blog post http://blog.roseman.org.uk/tag/iterm2.html in which a guy who works for Google says that he can use `XQuartz`, `iTerm2`, and `vim` and have things he `yanks` in `vim` copied to the system pasteboard, which syncs with his local clipboard.

I've installed `XQuartz`, changed preferences and checked the boxes to sync the pasteboards, and connected to ssh remotely with X forwarding (`ssh -X`) but when I yank things in `vim` to the system pasteboard (`"+yy`) on a remote system, my local clipboard does not change.

**What am I doing wrong? Do I need to be using `tmux` to have the pasteboards sync?**

I'm going into this a little blind having not used the pasteboard in command-line linux before. Can someone help me understand a little more on this subject?

Comment: I don't understand whether you have an X server available or not. If you do, you're looking for `xsel`/`xclip`, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bxsel%20%2Bxclip

Comment: After much research (and frustration) yesterday and today, I do have an x server running and xsel / xclip seem to be doing the trick. Thanks @Gilles!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a version of vim that was compiled with X support. You can run `gvim -v` (after installing gvim, of course) to run an appropriate version in a terminal.

Comment: Are you suggesting I need to install `gvim` on the remote (terminal only) system that I am ssh'ing to?

Comment: That is correct. You will also need the X libraries (which should be pulled in as a dependency), but not a full X server.

Comment: On ubuntu typing `apt-get install gvim` gives me options for `vim-gtk`, `vim-athena` or `vim-gnome`. I don't have a desktop installed on the machine so I'm guessing it would not be `gnome` - Maybe I could also just install `xclip` and use that with regular `vim` ? also +1 for helping me out.

Comment: `vim-gtk` will do. You don't need the features of Gnome, and Athena is a bit obsolescent on modern systems.

Comment: Got it working after using XQuartz, enabling the clipboard sync options, restarting, enabling X forwarding, and then specifying the system clipboard for the copy and paste operations.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

- configure OSX X11 to share the clipboard
- forward X11 between OSX and server
- use vim compiled with +xterm_clipboard
- optional: 'set clipboard=unnamedplus' to use system clipboard for default operations.

It sounds like you were using a version of vim compiled without +xterm_clipboard.  You can check via `vim --version | grep xterm_clipboard`.   I have `vim-nox` and `vim-gtk` installed on my ubuntu server.

Details here: 
http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2012/09/osx-remote-vim-clipboard-sync.html